# Devise + Omniauth + Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I've followed the [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2) video #235 and #236 to setup OmniAuth w/ Devise. I can get everything to work fine, my issues comes when I add the conditional statements in the authentications controller. I receive the following error:

NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#facebook
undefined method `to_key' for :user:Symbol
It seems to be crapping out at:

```
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
```

I've checked other answers here and none seems to have a solution. I found one related to Heroku, but I'm getting this message in development. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

authentications_controller.rb

```
def facebook
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth.provider, omniauth.uid)
    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      @user = User.new
      @user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, @user)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
    class RegistrationsController  Devise::RegistrationsController
      def create
        super
        session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
      end

      private

      def build_resource(*args)
        super
        if session[:omniauth]
          @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
          @user.valid?
        end
      end
    end
```

routes.rb

```
    resources :authentications
      get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#facebook'
      devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :omniauth_callbacks => 'authentications'}
```

user.rb

```
    class User  ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :authentications

      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

      def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
        self.email = omniauth.info.email if email.blank?
        authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      end

      def password_required?
        (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
      end
    end
```

Log

```
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
I, [2014-04-09T20:17:07.296969 #2248]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
I, [2014-04-09T20:17:07.353447 #2248]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
I, [2014-04-09T20:17:07.518464 #2248]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by AuthenticationsController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQC6I3SgbGI86ZBptFdBal5HIE1UHwCt7Zw5FVzGvWtApGhZfxjmXTo-AX3qJGOA_PWOeMK4i05K2yJL4_8bQLaTUjyvOBO4nQHjz2nLv5CTCMg2fPAsveUquO-UdVA8XajfUai9AQ8U8m4tfkwxysnq4n2bGBot2UCmFcfRGDB_b9uoIO8ELj80ltc3T0Vf2wj6XScl_R5m1o3CTUYqUzLQCukyjCb3Mz5_2_cWvHiCJLEiTMWjwccbrqNFhWgFCDNE0sLWZnESFNbdWUvFb_ug0NoXk4JevtQjv9XbW-FBiZ3FACn49grGlum1Z0I6qbI", "state"=>"758f521ee2e37251f404435d13e5f194fc7dab59cb412659"}
  Authentication Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "authentications".* FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "authentications"."uid" = '578621157' ORDER BY "authentications"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (7.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 124ms
  Rendered /Users/csmears/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/csmears/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/csmears/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/csmears/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (35.6ms)
```

Comment: I've also checked out the devise and omniauth documentation, but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the hash formatting. I changed it:

```
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user.user_id)
```

and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
```

To

```
sign_in_and_redirect(authentication.user)
```

Comment: change results in a new error: RuntimeError in AuthenticationsController#facebook
Could not find a valid mapping for nil

Comment: Can you share the server log generated for this error. Post it in the question.